# Two Round Feistel network

Tags: encryption, des, pseudo-random-permutation, feistel-network, luby-rackoff

While reading on block ciphers and DES I read that two-round Feistel network is not a secure PRP? Is there any easy to understand proof to explain the intuition behind this statement. I did search around and also reviewed this [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14567/exercise-attack-on-a-two-round-des-cipher) but wasn't really able to understand why it isn't secure PRP. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The key-word is _Luby and Rackoff construction_

Comment: Yes I read that and it didn't make sense to me maybe because of the notations used here: https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/crypto/prp.html Is there an easy to understand explanation like an example or proof?

Comment: [Q: Luby-Rackoff theorem confusion](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18611/18298) and [and search](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=Rackoff)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I read that two-round [Feistel network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher) is not a secure PRP

That's easily seen:

[image: two-rounds Feistel cipher]

It holds $P_L\oplus C_L=F_0(P_R)$. That implies a distinguishable property: for any fixed $P_R$ and whatever the round function $F_0$, when we flip bit(s) in $P_L$, that flips the corresponding bit(s) in $C_L$ and leaves the other bit(s) in $C_L$ unchanged.

That property allows a break under [Chosen Plaintext Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-plaintext_attack).

Comment: Perfect simple explanation that I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Umm... Isn't that 1-round Feistel?

Comment: @hola: the common way of counting rounds in Feistel ciphers is counting how many round functions there are. In the picture, there are two.