# An algorithm to break 2DES with less operations than exhaustive search

Tags: des

> **Exercise 3.6 from Cryptography and Engineering** Consider a new block cipher, DES2, that consists only of
> two rounds of the DES block cipher. DES2 has the same block and key
> size as DES. For this question you should consider the DES F function
> as a black box that takes two inputs, a 32-bit data segment and a
> 48-bit round key, and that produces a 32-bit output. Suppose you have
> a large number of plaintext-ciphertext pairs for DES2 under a single,
> unknown key. Give an algorithm for recovering the 48-bit round key for
> round 1 and the 48-bit round key for round 2. Your algorithm should
> require fewer operations than an exhaustive search for an entire
> 56-bit DES key. Can your algorithm be converted into a distinguishing
> attack against DES2?

My idea was if we have plaintext-ciphertext pair we do the following.
We split our ciphertext C in two 32bits. We have to guess K2 with 2^48 operations and then XOR L with output of F(K2,C) and compare with R of plaintext. If its equal we know K2 was correct. To make sure K2 was really correct, we can use other pairs to confirm it. Now we have to find K1, again with 2^48 operations. In total we need 2*2^48 operations rather 2^48 * 2^48 or better 2^56 operations. And we could easily use a distinguishing attack, by using weak keys of DES? and trying to find this L and R equality by only 2^48 operations. I might be totally wrong from the ground. Did I even draw the "2DES" cipher correctly?
[image: Structure of 2DES]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is largely answered here

[Exercise: Attack on a Two-Round DES Cipher](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14567/exercise-attack-on-a-two-round-des-cipher?rq=1)

Since the key is unknown to you, how are you going to mount a distinguishing attack? Think about that.